# Using GroupBy in .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I need to grouping in the result of my query. The main problem is that when I use GroupBy, the return type of GroupBy statement is `IGrouping` that is different from the return type of my method which is `List<MyViewModel>`. So theses two types does not match. Now the first option is to change the return type of my method. In this case how I can access to the properties of my ViewModel in view layer(HTML part of Razor Page)?

Is there any option to using GroupBy without changing the return type of my method?

```
            public List<MultimediaViewModel> Search(MultimediaSearchModel searchModel)
    {
        
        var query = _hContext.Multimedias.Include(x => x.Ceremony)
            .Select(g => new MultimediaViewModel
        {
            Id = g.Id,
            Title = g.Title,
            CeremonyId = g.CeremonyId,
            Ceremony = g.Ceremony.Title,
            FileAddress = g.FileAddress,
        }).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(g => g.CeremonyId).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchModel.Title))
            query = query.Where(g => g.Title.Contains(searchModel.Title)).ToList();

        if (searchModel.CeremonyId != 0)
            query = query.Where(g => g.Key == searchModel.CeremonyId).ToList();

        return query;
    }
```

the above code is not working because of the difference between method return type and Group by return type.

Comment: There is no way to do that automatically. After GroupBy you have only `IGrouping` result, which should be remapped later. What is the point to group by CeremonyId? It should have appropriate reason in `MultimediaViewModel`

Comment: For each distinct ceremonyId there might be several Mulitimedias. Which one do you want?

Comment: For each ceremonyId there might be several Mulitimedias. so when we want to save each multimedia item, we should assign it to the ceremony by CeremonyId which is forignkey of Ceremony model in Multimedia model.

Comment: There are several overloads for [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1), one of which returns an `IEnumerable<TResult>`. Use one of the overloads the provides the return type you desire.

Comment: @Amin, better to update question with `MultimediaViewModel` definition.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv     public class MultimediaViewModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get;  set; }
        public string FileAddress { get;  set; }
        public long CeremonyId { get;  set; }
        public string Ceremony { get; set; }

    }

Comment: @Amin, better to edit your question, not a comment. Anyway, if you groupby by some filed, others should be calculated as an aggregation function. It is how GroupBy works - group items by some fields and return aggregation result with grouping fields. Maybe you do not need Grouping? Or you have algorithm which data should be returned?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The problem is different from the point that you told. The main problem is the return type of Group by which is not the same return type of method!!

Comment: So why do you group if you want to return the data in a type that can't convey any grouping information? It's just a list. How does the UI know anything about grouping?

Comment: @GertArnold  let me explain my problem. I need to list all ceremonies incase of my searchModel parameters are empty. So When the page loaded, we should have a list of multimedia albums of ceremonies. already we have this list but ceremony repeat per each multimedia item. I want to change this search method to return me multimedia items based on its ceremony. For example assume that we have 3 ceremonies. and for each ceremony we have 4 multimedia items. Now the list is showing us 12 rows, while it is expected to have 3 rows.

Comment: As you already explained. But you're not answering my question. The return type doesn't know anything about grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without knowing your business needs completely I can offer 2 ways to get around this

1. use the GroupBy outside the method, use the Search method to return a list and then use GroupBy to group it
2. if you only need to return a list of MultimediaViewModel for a specific CeremonyId, you can search the list of IGrouping to get a specific sub list

   ```
    public List<MultimediaViewModel> Search(MultimediaSearchModel searchModel)
       {
           var query = _hContext.Multimedias.Include(x => x.Ceremony).Select(g => new MultimediaViewModel
           {
               Id = g.Id,
               Title = g.Title,
               CeremonyId = g.CeremonyId,
               Ceremony = g.Ceremony.Title,
               FileAddress = g.FileAddress
           }).GroupBy(g => g.CeremonyId).ToList();  

    return query.FirstOrDefault(g=>g.Key==searchModel.CeremonyId).ToList();
    //you can just use Where to find all  of the MultimediaViewModel instead of using GroupBy
   ```

EDIT
maybe return the result as a Dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, List<MultimediaViewModel>> Search(MultimediaSearchModel searchModel)
{
    var query = _hContext.Multimedias.Include(x => x.Ceremony).Select(g => new MultimediaViewModel
    {
        Id = g.Id,
        Title = g.Title,
        CeremonyId = g.CeremonyId,
        Ceremony = g.Ceremony.Title,
        FileAddress = g.FileAddress
    }).GroupBy(g => g.CeremonyId).ToList();
    return query.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for your reply. but let me explain my problem. I need to list all ceremonies incase of my searchModel parameters are empty. So When the page loaded, we should have a list of multimedia albums of ceremonies. already we have this list but ceremony repeat per each multimedia item. I want to change this saerch method to return me multimedia items based on its ceremony. For example assume that we have 3 ceremonies. and for each ceremony we have 4 multimedia items. Now the list is showing us 12 rows, while it is expected to have 3 rows.

Comment: Would you please advice how can use Group By outside method?

Comment: based on your answer i think you need to return a dictionary of CeremonyId to a list of MultimediaViewModel

i have edited my answer with a way to do this

Comment: I have edited my method based on your comment but received the following error: 
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<long, System.Collections.Generic.List<xxx.Application.Contracts.Multimedia.MultimediaViewModel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<xxx.Application.Contracts.Multimedia.MultimediaViewModel>>' xxx.Infrastructure.EFCore

Comment: I have changed type string to long, the problem solved but I don't know how can access to the following items and its values in HTML part of my razor page?   Id,Title,CeremonyId,Ceremony,FileAddress

Comment: In fact I need to access items of MultimediaViewModel to arrange it to a table in my razor page.